# "Pin to taskbar" disappeared

Tags: windows-11

When I right-clicked a shortcut on the desktop, I used to have an option to pin it to the taskbar. I'm not sure when, but it disappeared. How do I pin shortcuts to the taskbar?

Comment: is it really not there in 11? it is still here in 10 (21H2)

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: the issue was limited to batch files (.bat). Need to add to their shortcut command line `cmd /c`.